# AngularJS inheritance of 'config' from one module to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I have two modules, like the following ones:

```
var a = angular.module('a', []);
a.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']>');
}]);

var b = angular.module('b', ['a']);
```

I'm running some tests, but I can't figure out if the interpolate configuration in `a` module is being inherited in `b` module.

Does angular inherit the `config` of modules into another modules?

Comment: yes..it does inherit the config..what is your issue?

Comment: @PankajParkar How can I make the `b` module not inherit the config of `a`?

Comment: I'm not sure about it..but it think you can not...

Comment: @alexandernst you can't, the way angular bootstraps itself means that any configuration applied in dependant modules is applied (and overriden) by any configuration applied in the bootstrapping module. This makes more sense as it always means that the top-most module always has the final say in how an application is configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance isn't the issue here, you are configuring a provider that is used by both modules, and angular is going to apply each `config` in the order that you register them. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

> When bootstrapping, first Angular applies all constant definitions.
>   Then Angular applies configuration blocks in the same order they were
>   registered.

You can reset the values of `$interpolateProvider` start and end symbols, but you cannot have both settings in your application since you are modifying the *same* provider in each `config` block.

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview) showing this in action.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for clarifying.